# My program that is supposed to get rid of characters that are not numbers doesn't fully work, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a program that is supposed to take user input and then go through the input and remove all of the characters in the string that are not numbers and then print the string after the characters have been removed. I believe that my code is correct, but it doesn't seem to completely do the job, mainly the last character in the string. I think my problem is in the code that checks each character, as it seems to be leaving some characters out. Here's my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string separate(string inString){
    string numbers = "1234567890";
    string oString = "";
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<inString.size()-1; k++){
        if ((numbers.find(inString[k]) == string::npos) && (numbers.find(inString[k+1]) != string::npos) && !isspace(inString[k+1])){
            oString += inString.substr(k,1) = "";
        }
        else if ((numbers.find(inString[k]) != string::npos) && (numbers.find(inString[k+1]) == string::npos) && !isspace(inString[k+1])){
            oString += inString.substr(k,1);
        }
        else if (isspace(inString[k+1])){
            oString += inString.substr(k,1) = "";
            oString += inString.substr(k,1);
        }
        else oString += inString.substr(k,1);
    }
    oString += inString.substr(k,1);
    return oString;
}

int main(){
    string mystr;
    cin >> mystr;

    cout << separate(mystr) << endl;
}
```

Thanks for any help that you guys could give me. I'm new to C++, so any help is good.

Comment: Umm..If you're willing to really use C++, this can be accomplished in 2 lines, maybe 1 line.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, wouldn't a simple and non-convoluded way be to just iterate through each character in the string and check ascii values? Not the most efficient, but an easy algorithm to implement for this problem?

Comment: If this is an assignment, there'd be restrictions. What functions can you not use? Can you give sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI What is convoluted about `remove_if` and `erase`?  Does it require 20 lines of code?  The attempt of the OP is very bad, calling `substr` an umpteen number of times.  Why?

Comment: No sorry, I meant that his way he has right now is very convoluded, and to either use what you suggested other functions that reduce this down to a few lines of code, or just iterate through and check ascii values.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI -- Then even if you did that, you need to call `erase` to remove the character, and be careful of incrementing the loop, etc.  It still becomes error prone.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I would just make a vector that stores the final result and not mess with any string functions. I would just loop through util hit the null terminator or length of string, and if the ascii value of that character is not the ascii of that integer I would push_back that character to the vector, and easily print the vector with the final result

Comment: calling `substr` and `find` so many times like that is too expensive

Comment: @OmidCompSCI So let's say the string is 10,000 characters long.  The problem with your approach is that you now could potentially be creating a vector of 10,000 (worst case).  In addition, it really does go against good C++ programming to resort to something that is easily provided by the algorithm functions.  Read up on what people like Sean Parent have to say about writing "hand-coded" (similar to the OP's), buggy solutions without exploring the things that algorithm functions can do.

Comment: Alex, this isn't an assignment. I'm doing this outside of school.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you for bringing this up and your answer example. I am still a student as a computer science major, and I have been brainwashed into these types of algorithms and not thinking about situations of space vs time, etc. I have been really starting to learn about the STL libraries and what they have to offer. Unfortunately they never go over the STL in school. Hopefully can be good as you one day!

Comment: @OmidCompSCI You may find that they rarely cover C++ either.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI - A lot of universities teach C++ as merely `C` with some C++ syntax thrown in.  You really have to find that rare institution or do independent research if you really want to learn the language properly.  However, if you really wanted to do this "correctly" without the algorithm functions, you should have swapped out the removed character to the end of the sequence, similar to how `remove_if` would have done it, without having to create a vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You tagged this as C++, so let's use it.  The `std::string` class has an `erase` method.  Using that and the [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm is all you need.  This is known as the `remove / erase` idiom.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
//...
string separate(string inString)
{
   // move all the erased items to end of the string, and point to where
   // the erased items are. 
   auto iterToErasedItems = std::remove_if(inString.begin(), inString.end(), [] (char ch) { return !::isdigit(ch); });

   // now erase them. 
   inString.erase(iterToErasedItems, inString.end());

   // return the string.
   return inString;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/g2yrJc)

The `std::remove_if` is an algorithm function that goes through the sequence and "removes" the item that matches the criteria given in the third argument.  The criteria happens to be everything that is not a digit (the `::isdigit` helps us here).

Note that the items are not physically removed, just placed at the tail end of the sequence.  The `remove_if` returns the iterator to where the removed items start, so we need to do some clean up work by calling `string::erase()` to physically remove the characters.  Done.

The other good thing about this approach is that this is 99% boilerplate code to erase any character from a string that matches a certain criteria.  All you need to do is change the third argument to `remove_if` to either a function pointer, functor, or a lambda that returns `true` if the character is to be erased, `false` otherwise.

For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
//...
string separate(string inString)
{
   // remove any 'a' characters from the string
   auto iterToErasedItems = std::remove_if(inString.begin(), inString.end(), 
                                          [](char ch) { return ch == 'a'; });

   // now erase them. 
   inString.erase(iterToErasedItems, inString.end());

   // return the string.
   return inString;
}
```

Edit:  Your post wanted to remove everything that is **not** a number, so the requisite changes have been made.

Comment: Say it: "remove/erase idiom" All the cool kids are saying it =P (upticked, btw).

Comment: Edited. Don't know why I forgot to include the well-known phrase.

Comment: That is so much simpler than my code! I didn't even know about string::erase and std::remove_if until now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EccentricTortoise I understand why university studies teach how they teach (they want to drill the *algorithm* design in; not off-the-shelf solution usage). But often off-the-shelf is so well explained you can get both. The link Paul provided is an outstanding site that frequently includes possible implementations (this is no exception to that). It is worth your time to review those and see how you could do what has (thankfully) already been done for you to fulfill the poorly disguised goal your university intends: to understand the algorithms. Best of luck!.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the advice, I'll follow it as best I can, as I am only in year 10 at the moment, so I'll need every bit of it before I get to university. Thanks for the link, Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can use recursion rather than for loops.

Recursion is a method that is extensively used in functional language like Haskell.

I have written a solution in Haskell:

```
delete [] x = []
delete (y:ys) x  = if x == y 
         then delete ys x
         else y:delete ys x


-- from Set Theory e.g. A \ B

difference xs [] = xs 
difference xs (y:ys) = difference (delete y xs) ys

main = do putStrLn (difference "a1b2b3" "123456789")
```

The code in c++ is more complex.

Also, just as in functional programming, try to use functions whenever possible to make your code more neat.

Answer (score -1):

This line

```
for(k=0; k<inString.size()-1; k++){
```

Should be:

```
for(k=0; k<inString.size(); k++){
```

Let's say your string is "14u3j".
The size of this string is 5.
with inString.size() - 1 you would iterate the first 4 characters in the string (0, 1, 2, 3) and would not iterate through the last one.

This is a common mistake in programming referred to as off-by-one-error, where you accidentally iterate a loop one extra time or, as in your case, one time less.

#### Edit

As pointed out by @Alex, this will give you an error in this part of the code.

```
numbers.find(inString[k+1]
```

I suggest you check @nshtc's answer for a more comprehensive algorithm.

I'll leave this answer here just because of the explanation about why, in your algorithm, the last character is not being iterated.

Comment: `numbers.find(inString[k+1]` wouldn't be valid then

Comment: You are right, i just glimpsed through the code and forgot to look the rest of it. I will update with a better answer and recommendation in a while. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why the last character was being ignored, I was so confused.